# Dev server restarts itself due to "file change" when inserting data with Sequelize into SQLITE DB, does not occur with MySQL [Repo included]

Tags: node.js, sqlite, graphql, sequelize.js, nestjs

## Issue

`this.userModel.create({email, password })` [[github]](https://github.com/hkyq/nest_prob/blob/b38105176303f34fbd8ebb57d008fe25ca444c81/src/user/user.service.ts#L13) causes the Nest dev server to restart itself when there is a fresh sqlite db. Called from [here](https://github.com/hkyq/nest_prob/blob/master/src/user/user.resolver.ts#L12)

[Here](https://pastebin.com/raw/WfQW1GhL) is the dev server log. I run the mutation below at `Executing (default): INSERT INTO UserModels ...`

I don't think this is an issue with my module importing or something like that because things like `this.userModel.findAll()` work.

## Reproducing

[Here](https://github.com/hkyq/nest_prob/) is a minimal GraphQL repo where the issues occurs.

To see the error, you can do `npm run start:dev` then go to `localhost:3000/graphql` and send

```
mutation {
  signUp(signUpInput: {password: "passwordpassword" email: "email@email.com"})
}
```

The server should restart itself.

## Solution

In [`app.module.ts`](https://github.com/hkyq/nest_prob/blob/b38105176303f34fbd8ebb57d008fe25ca444c81/src/user/user.service.ts#L13), using MySQL instead of sqlite solves the issue. But I am not sure why. To make sure it is not an issue with sqlite or Sequelize, I have replaced MySQL with Sqlite in a Nest/Sequelize [example app](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/07-sequelize/src) which worked.

Comment: You should split your question into two -- one about the warnings you're seeing and one about the server reloading. There's no indication that these are related. Also, you should include the exact text of the warnings -- while including a minimal repo is super helpful, you shouldn't expect people to run your code just to see the warnings.

Comment: That aside, are you also able to trigger the server restarting if you change any other file inside your directory, for example by changing the `description` inside `package.json`?

Comment: @DanielRearden Thanks for the feedback. I've edited my question to focus on the major issue and provided more details. And no, changing package.json does not trigger a restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting

```
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
```

in tsconfig
fixes it